# How to write test cases for a function calling another function in qunit?

Tags: qunit

I have a function A which looks like this in controller1.
This function calls another function B in controller 2.
Can someone help me write qunit for this ?

```
A: function(){
//This function calls function B in controller2.
controller2.B(a);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Looks like this is related to your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396936/how-can-the-stubbing-be-done-in-qunit)? I think we need a bit more on the two functions here... Is `A` an object? Maybe you could expand this example a bit more? Like what does `B()` return? What do you want to test exactly?

Comment: Can you provide minimal, complete code.